# Write a regular expression whose output will only be rows in a range 01/03/2021 - 01/03/2020

Tags: linux, text-processing, grep

I have a file that got dates from 01/01/2020 to 04/04/2021
I want to get only the dates between 01/03/2020 to 01/03/2021 by using egrep. I tried to do

```
egrep "([0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0]/[0][3-9]|[1][0-2]/[2][0][2][0-1])$" dates.txt
```

but it is still giving me all the dates in the file:

```
$ cat dates.txt 
01/01/2020
24/01/2020
04/02/2020
23/02/2020
01/03/2020
13/03/2020
14/04/2020
29/05/2020
16/06/2020
17/07/2020
18/08/2020
19/09/2020
20/10/2020
21/11/2020
22/12/2020
23/01/2021
24/02/2021
01/03/2021
25/03/2021
04/04/2021
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see a few examples of complete lines containing dates from both inside and outside of the range of dates that you're interested in. Without seeing this, it's unclear what other data may be part of the text and how specific the matching has to be.

Comment: thats screenshot of what the dates and the egrep i tried to use https://prnt.sc/Dghj1MvPsTE0

Comment: Edit your question to include the text of your input data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really wouldn't try to do this with just regular expressions. More sophisticated tools will make it easier. For example, with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F/ '($3==2020 && $2 > 2) || ($3==2021 && ($2 < 3) || ($1< 2 && $2 == 3))' dates.txt 
01/03/2020
13/03/2020
14/04/2020
29/05/2020
16/06/2020
17/07/2020
18/08/2020
19/09/2020
20/10/2020
21/11/2020
22/12/2020
23/01/2021
24/02/2021
01/03/2021
```

The `awk` is setting the field separator to `/` and then simply selecting lines that match one of these three criteria:

- the last field (the year) is `2020` and the second field (the month) is greater than `2`. This will match all dates from `01/03/2020` until `31/12/2020`.
- the last field (the year) is `2021` and either

  - the second field (the month) is smaller than `3` OR
  - the first field (the day of the month) is less than `2` and the second field (the month) is exactly `3`.

Answer (score 5):

Using the example file given, where dates are in order and the start + end date are present in the file, you might find a solution using `awk` to be more straightforward.

```
$ awk '$1=="01/03/2020",$1=="01/03/2021"' dates.txt
01/03/2020
13/03/2020
14/04/2020
29/05/2020
16/06/2020
17/07/2020
18/08/2020
19/09/2020
20/10/2020
21/11/2020
22/12/2020
23/01/2021
24/02/2021
01/03/2021
$
```

As an aside, do be aware that use of `egrep` is [deprecated](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/grep-Programs.html#grep-Programs), in favour of the POSIX-compliant `grep -E` approach.

Comment: using AWK is right if the file is sorted right but if its not sorted its wont work like in this qustion i have to work on the dates not the line so egrep or the grep -E is more right than awk

Comment: @Mohamad egrep and grep -E just do what awk does by default, i.e. match an ERE against your input and print the matching line, so saying `egrep or the grep -E is more right than awk` is just not accurate from that standpoint plus awk has better capabilities for this kind of problem so an awk solution will be better than a grep one for this.

Answer (score 2):

From your description you need any date from year 2020 after `01/03/2020`. That would be:

```
$ egrep "(../(0[3-9]|1[0-2])/2020$)" dates.txt
```

And also all dates from 2021 up to `01/03/2021`. That part would be:

```
$ egrep "((/0[1-2]/|01/03/)2021$)" dates.txt
```

Joining both ranges:

```
$ egrep "(../(0[3-9]|1[0-2])/2020$|(/0[1-2]/|01/03/)2021$)" dates.txt
```

Simplifying a little bit, changing to `grep -E` (which is the present day equivalent to egrep), and listing the output:

```
$ grep -E "(/(0[3-9]|1[0-2])/2020|(/0[1-2]/|01/03/)2021)$" dates.txt
01/03/2020
13/03/2020
14/04/2020
29/05/2020
16/06/2020
17/07/2020
18/08/2020
19/09/2020
20/10/2020
21/11/2020
22/12/2020
23/01/2021
24/02/2021
01/03/2021
```

Your source file seems to be:

```
$ cat dates.txt 
01/01/2020
24/01/2020
04/02/2020
23/02/2020
01/03/2020
13/03/2020
14/04/2020
29/05/2020
16/06/2020
17/07/2020
18/08/2020
19/09/2020
20/10/2020
21/11/2020
22/12/2020
23/01/2021
24/02/2021
01/03/2021
25/03/2021
04/04/2021
```

Comment: yea thats right really thanks alot i got edit it to $ grep -E "(/(0[3-9]|1[0-2])/2020|(/0[1-2]/|01/03/)2021))$" dates.txt to include the month 10

Comment: btw is there is another way to do that ?

Comment: @MohamadAboallo Yes, answer edited to include month 10.

Comment: @MohamadAboallo To do *what* in *which* way? With perl, sed, awk? or using something that is not a regex, or exactly what do you mean?

Comment: thanks alot i have figure it out <3

Comment: @MohamadAboallo As listed in my answer, the result of the command do include `23/01/2021` and `24/02/2021`.

Comment: If this answer has been useful to you please consider *accepting* it. read: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234 @MohamadAboallo

Answer (score 2):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne 'my $ts = .subst(/ ^ (\d**2) \/ (\d**2) \/ (\d**4) /, {"$2-$1-$0"}).Date; say $ts if Date.new("2020-03-01") < $ts < Date.new
("2021-03-01");'
```

Raku handles `ISO-8601` dates by default, as long as you provide a string in the right format (hyphen-separated `yyyy-mm-dd`). The code above captures the digits, re-arranges them, and creates `Date` objects. Then a *"startdate < $timestamp < enddate"* conditional is used to select out the desired range.

Sample Input:

```
01/01/2020
24/01/2020
04/02/2020
23/02/2020
01/03/2020
13/03/2020
14/04/2020
29/05/2020
16/06/2020
17/07/2020
18/08/2020
19/09/2020
20/10/2020
21/11/2020
22/12/2020
23/01/2021
24/02/2021
01/03/2021
25/03/2021
04/04/2021
```

Sample Output:

```
2020-03-13
2020-04-14
2020-05-29
2020-06-16
2020-07-17
2020-08-18
2020-09-19
2020-10-20
2020-11-21
2020-12-22
2021-01-23
2021-02-24
```

*[With the Raku code described here, a nice check with `ISO-8601` Date conversion is that it will balk at months > 12, helping to ensure that months/days don't get scrambled].*

Below, there's a more compact solution (possibly at the expense of readability), that preserves the dates in the original format:

```bash
~$ raku -ne '.say if Date.new("2020-03-01") < S/ ^ (\d**2) \/ (\d**2) \/ (\d**4) /{"$2-$1-$0"}/.Date < Date.new("2021-03-01");' file
13/03/2020
14/04/2020
29/05/2020
16/06/2020
17/07/2020
18/08/2020
19/09/2020
20/10/2020
21/11/2020
22/12/2020
23/01/2021
24/02/2021
```

https://docs.raku.org/type/Date
https://raku.org

Answer (score 1):

Just use awk:

```
$ awk -F'/' '{d=$3$2$1} (20200301 <= d) && (d <= 20210301)' dates.txt
01/03/2020
13/03/2020
14/04/2020
29/05/2020
16/06/2020
17/07/2020
18/08/2020
19/09/2020
20/10/2020
21/11/2020
22/12/2020
23/01/2021
24/02/2021
01/03/2021
```

The above will work whether the input is sorted or not and whether the range-delimiting dates are present in the input or not.

Just change `<=` to `<` if by `between` you meant excluding the delimiting dates.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question with the tool requested, the problem lies in grouping.  In particular, if you write the regular expression as:

```
([0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0]/[0][3-9]|[1][0-2]/[2][0][2][0-1])$
```

This will match anything matching any of:

```
[0][1-9]$
[1-2][0-9]%
[3][0]/[0][3-9]$
[1][0-2]/[2][0][2][0-1]$
```

Try instead the command:

```
egrep "[0-9][0-9]/(((0[3-9]|1[012])/2020)|(0[12]/2021))$" dates.txt
```

Note that I have removed any attempt at date validation in the expression, just matching.  I wouldn't recommend trying to do both.

It isn't clear to me if you wanted 01/03/2021 to match.  If you did, I would add an or clause to match just that, as:

```
egrep "([0-9][0-9]/(((0[3-9]|1[012])/2020)|(0[12]/2021)))$|01/03/2021$" dates.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`GNU grep` supports `PCRE` mode, where we can use as shown:

```
grep -P '(?x) (?:01/03|/0[12])/2021 | /(?!0[12])../2020' file
```

---

We can do it in `perl` by writing the regex in multi lines:

```bash
perl -ne 'print if
  m{
    (?:
      (?:01/03/2021)      |
      (?:/(?:0[12])/2021) |
      (?:/(?!0[12])../2020)
    )
  }x;' file
```

---

`sed` equivalent is as shown where we keep deleting impossibilities, and at the end what remains is the desired answer.

```bash
sed -e '
  \:01/03/2021$:!{
  \:/0[12]/2021$:!{
  \:/2020$:!d
  \:/0[12]/:d
  };}
' file
```

---

```bash
sed -e '
  \:01/03/2021$:b
  \:/0[12]/2021$:b
  \:/2020$:{
    \:/0[12]/:!b
  };d
' file
```

---

```bash
sed -En '1{x
  s:.*:20200301-20210301#0123456789:
x;}
  s:^(..)/(..)/(.{4}):&\n\3\2\1:;G
  /\n(.*)(.).*\n\1(.).*#.*\2.*\3/d
  /\n(.*)(.).*\-\1(.).*#.*\3.*\2/d
  P
' file
```

---